# Query on Mongoid Hash Field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid, nosql

I want to query on a Hash field for a Mongoid Class. I'm not sure how I can do this with conditions?

Here is an example:

```
class Person
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :things, :type => Hash
end
```

So, let's say that I have this:

```
p = Person.new
p.things = {}
p.things[:tv] = "Samsung"
```

I want to query for the first person with a tv that is a Samsung...

```
People.first(:conditions => ?????
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

```
Person.where('things.tv' => 'Samsung').first
```

This is where Mongoid and MongoDB really shine. Mongoid's Criteria methods (`Person.where`, `Person.any_of`, `Person.excludes`, etc.) will give you much more flexibility than the ActiveRecord-style finders (passing a `:conditions` hash to `Person.find`, `Person.first`, etc.)

Mongoid's site has some great documentation on how to use `Criteria`:

http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/querying.html

Comment: When I try that I get the following error: "BSON::InvalidKeyName: key must not contain '.'"

Comment: Nevermind. That error was when I was trying to use that syntax on my ".create" method. Thanks, it worked great.

Comment: Well, now the problem is that when People is persisted using "save" and then later retrieved using the "where" method, you can no longer access p.things[:tv].. it has to be p.things['tv']. Mongoid converts it to string. Any thoughts on why that would be?

Comment: The keys of a hash have to be strings according to the BSON spec. It's technically not valid to use p.things[:tv] to set the value, but Mongoid is converting to string for you. This is an issue with MongoDB itself: 
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Frequently+Asked+Questions+-+Ruby#FrequentlyAskedQuestions-Ruby-IseethatBSONsupportsasymboltype.DoesthismeanthatIcanstoreRubysymbolsinMongoDB%3F

You can store symbols as values, though. For the keys, you'll just have to use p.things['tv'] .

Comment: No, actually @bowsersenior , you make this point much more clear than the MongoID docs page.  I read it several times and didn't grok this.

Comment: It looks like you're querying a value of the hash - is it possible to query a key of the hash instead?  Also, if you index the hash field, will it be used on a value lookup?  Key lookup?  Thanks this is helpful!

Comment: Hi Brian, I am not sure if Mongoid has a helper to query for a key. You may have to pass a raw MongoDB query using `$exists` . See the MongoDB docs for more info: 
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24exists

I think the latest MongoDB versions (2.x) should use indexes for the lookup, but you should confirm for yourself by looking into the official docs (try http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Indexes).